# How do I serialize an AppDomain to disk

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, appdomain

I want to serialize the state of separated parts of my .Net application, without writing any complex custom serialization code. 
The application already uses a separate AppDomains for each "Task", and will unload an AppDomain if it decides the "Task" is misbehaving.

I want to be able to save and load these Tasks from disk, without having to write binary serializers for a complex object tree. I figured the separation provided by an AppDomain might make an universal solution for this possible.

Any idea how I might go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, basically. You can't serialize an entire `AppDomain`. You could use low level tools to snapshot it (effectively a dump file), but it would never work again. If you want to serialize the state of a complex operation, you'll need to figure out an object model and serialization strategy that supports that.

Comment: Ok - had hoped there'd be a magic short-cut, but it seems not.